# Parsing XML attributes in java

Tags: java, xml, dom, xml-parsing

I have an xml similar to this

```
<Applications>
  <ApplicationID>
    <VendorId value="0" />
    <AuthApplId value="4" />
    <AcctApplId value="0" />
  </ApplicationID>
  <ApplicationID>
    <VendorId value="193" />
    <AuthApplId value="0" />
    <AcctApplId value="19302" />
  </ApplicationID>
</Applications>
```

I want to parse this and store to Strings Like VendorId, AuthApplId etc. I got ApplicationID  parsed with `getElementsByTagName("ApplicationID")` if it was `<ApplicationID  value="somevalue"/>` then I can use `getAttribute("value")` method. but in the above mentioned situation what should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
NodeList applicationIDNodes = getElementsByTagName("ApplicationID");
for (int i = 0; i < applicationIDNodes.length; i++) {
   Node applicationIDNode = applciationIdNodes.getItem(i);
   NodeList applicationIdChildren = applicationIdNode.getChildren();

   String vendorId = applicationIdChildren.getItem(0).getAttribute("value").value();
   String authAppliId = applicationIdChildren.getItem(1).getAttribute("value").value();
   String actApplID = applicationIdChildren.getItem(2).getAttribute("value").value();

   // do whathever you want with vendorId, authAppliId, actApplID       
}
```

Comment: There is no such method getItem() in NodeList interface

Comment: applicationIdChildren.getItem(0).getAttribute("value").value();            getAttribute - method is also not there - pls explain